# For a VBS file, is there a line of code, a command, or script that will simulate a left mouse button click?

Tags: vbscript, click, mouse

For a .VBS file, is there a line of code, a command, or script that will simulate a left mouse button click?

For example:

...

WshShell.SendKeys "3"

WScript.Sleep 5000

*code/command/script to perform left-click here*

WScript.Sleep 5000

WshShell.SendKeys "4"

...

I'm most interested in the code to enact the click, not interested in moving the mouse curser. Also, and this is very important, I am not writing this in html for a webpage. It is for a .VBS file on my desktop that I will be double-clicking to start the .VBS program and then the .VBS file will run its code and will eventually left-click whatever object is under the curser at that moment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. But Windows is a keyboard driven interface as well as mouse. You can select anything with the keyboard and press space to activate.

There is an interface to do this but it is in the .NET framework.

System.Windows.Automation. If you do your file as a vb.net script you'll be able to access it. Remember in VB.Net (you can write vbscript and it will work) everything has brackets, ie subs have brackets like functions.

This is how to make vb.net programs with only notepad. It links to two other articles.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df0248cb-612f-4e2f-9665-11c68c401458/how-to-call-win32-api-calls-in-vbscript-and-jscript-sample-windows-api-functions?forum=scripting

Anyway this is the dialog box keyboard interface.

Dialog Box Keyboard Interface
The system provides a special keyboard interface for dialog boxes that carries out special processing for several keys. The interface generates messages that correspond to certain buttons in the dialog box or changes the input focus from one control to another. Following are the keys used in this interface and their respective actions.

Key Action 
ALT+mnemonic Moves the input focus to the first control (having the WS_TABSTOP style) after the static control containing the specified mnemonic.

DOWN Moves the input focus to the next control in the group.

ENTER Sends a WM_COMMAND message to the dialog box procedure. The wParam parameter is set to IDOK or control identifier of the default push button.

ESC Sends a WM_COMMAND message to the dialog box procedure. The wParam parameter is set to IDCANCEL.

LEFT Moves the input focus to the previous control in the group. 
mnemonic Moves the input focus to the first control (having the WS_TABSTOP style) after the static control containing the specified mnemonic.

RIGHT Moves the input focus to the next control in the group.

SHIFT+TAB Moves the input focus to the previous control that has the WS_TABSTOP style.

TAB Moves the input focus to the next control that has the WS_TABSTOP style.

UP Moves the input focus to the previous control in the group.

The system automatically provides the keyboard interface for all modal dialog boxes. It does not provide the interface for modeless dialog boxes unless the application calls the IsDialogMessage function to filter messages in its main message loop. This means that the application must pass the message to IsDialogMessage immediately after retrieving the message from the message queue. The function processes the messages if it is for the dialog box and returns a nonzero value to indicate that the message has been processed and must not be passed to the TranslateMessage or DispatchMessage function.

Because the dialog box keyboard interface uses direction keys to move between controls in a dialog box, an application cannot use these keys to scroll the contents of any modal dialog box or any modeless dialog box for which IsDialogMessage is called. When a dialog box has scroll bars, the application must provide an alternate keyboard interface for the scroll bars. Note that the mouse interface for scrolling is available when the system includes a mouse.